# flask sqlalchemy many to many - using objects

Tags: python, many-to-many, flask-sqlalchemy

I have setup flask with sqlalchemy and mysql.  Everything is working but I am still really confused on how to access/use my association tables for my many to many relationships.  I have reviewed the documentation and I'm pretty sure I set it up right but not sure how I create records that fill out the junction(association) tables.

I have multiple many-to-many relationships -

```
users <--> teams
users <--> players
```

I also have a one-to-one relationship which I am using without issue -

```
users --> positions_bb
```

Below is my models.py file.  I am doing all my testing from the python CLI (taking the rest of the flask framework out of the picture).  Once I create a user how do I create an entry in the teams_users_map table that shows the user_id key and the team_id key??  I have tried:

```
t = models.Team(teamname='exteam')
u = models.User(email='bob@emailcom','password123')

t.user = 1 ('incompatible collection type: int is not list like'). Ok this makes sense - a list is expected.

t.user = [User(1)] - ('User is not defined').  This was just a guess at some examples I saw, didn't make sense to me anyway.

t.users = 1 - this actually did not return an error but it also didn't appear to save anything in the database.
```

In short, really stupid question I guess - how the heck do I add items to the junction table??

```
from werkzeug import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash
    from datetime import datetime,timedelta
    from ylm import db

    teams_users_map = db.Table('teams_users_map',
        db.Column('fk_team_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('teams.team_id')),
        db.Column('fk_user_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.user_id'))
    )

    teams_players_map = db.Table('teams_players_map',
        db.Column('fk_team_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('teams.team_id')),
        db.Column('fk_player_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('players.player_id'))
    )

    class User(db.Model):
        __tablename__ = 'users'
        user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
        email = db.Column(db.String(120))
        pwdhash = db.Column(db.String(200))
        create_date = db.Column(db.Date)
        active = db.Column(db.Integer)

        def __repr__(self):
            return 'UserID: %r\nEmail: %r\nPassword %r\nCreate Date: %r\nActive: %r\n\n' % (self.user_id,self.email,self.pwdhash,self.create_date,self.active)

        def is_authenticated(self):
            return True

        def is_active(self):
            return True

        def is_anonymous(self):
            return False

        def get_id(self):
            return unicode(self.user_id) 

        def __init__(self, email, password):
            self.email = email.lower()
            self.set_password(password)
            self.create_date = datetime.utcnow()
            self.active = 0

        def set_password(self, password):
            self.pwdhash = generate_password_hash(password)

        def check_password(self, password):
            return check_password_hash(self.pwdhash, password)

    class Team(db.Model):
        __tablename__ = 'teams'
        team_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
        teamname = db.Column(db.String(96), unique=True, nullable=False)
        sport = db.Column(db.String(32))
        age = db.Column(db.Integer())
        create_date = db.Column(db.Date)
        active = db.Column(db.Integer)
        user = db.relationship('User', secondary=teams_users_map, backref='teams')
        player = db.relationship('Player', secondary=teams_players_map, backref='teams')

        def __repr__(self):
            return "TeamID: %r\nTeamName: %r\nSport: %r\nAge: %r\nCreate Date: %r\nActive: %r\n\n" % (self.team_id,self.teamname,self.sport,self.age,self.create_date,self.active)

    class Player(db.Model):
        __tablename__ = 'players'
        player_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
        playername = db.Column(db.String(120), index=True, unique=True, nullable=False)
        address = db.Column(db.String(120))
        city = db.Column(db.String(48))
        state = db.Column(db.String(2))
        zip = db.Column(db.String(5))
        dob = db.Column(db.String(10))
        position = db.relationship("Position_bb", uselist=False, backref="players")

        def __repr__(self):
            return "PlayerID: %r\nPlayerName: %r\nAddress: %r\nCity: %r\nState: %r\nZip: %r\nDOB: %r\n" % (self.player_id,self.playername,self.address,self.city,self.state,self.zip,self.dob)

    class Position_bb(db.Model):
        __tablename__ = 'positions_bb'
        position_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
        p = db.Column(db.Integer(), default=5, nullable=False)
        c = db.Column(db.Integer(), default=5, nullable=False)
        fb = db.Column(db.Integer(), default=5, nullable=False)
        sb = db.Column(db.Integer(), default=5, nullable=False)
        tb = db.Column(db.Integer(), default=5, nullable=False)
        ss = db.Column(db.Integer(), default=5, nullable=False)
        lf = db.Column(db.Integer(), default=5, nullable=False)
        cf = db.Column(db.Integer(), default=5, nullable=False)
        rf = db.Column(db.Integer(), default=5, nullable=False)
        bench = db.Column(db.Integer(), default=5, nullable=False)
        available = db.Column(db.Integer(), default=5, nullable=False)
        fk_player = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('players.player_id'))

        def __repr__(self):
            return "PositionID: %r\nP: %r\nC: %r\n1B: %r\n2B: %r\n3B: %r\nSS: %r\nLF: %r\nCF: %r\nRF: %r\nBench: %r\nAvailable: %r\n" %(self.position_id,self.p,self.p,self.fb,self.sb,self.tb,self.ss,self.lf,self.cf,self.rf,self.bench,self.available)
```

Comment: Update - I was curious if using MySql was an issue as without InnoDB it doesn't support foreign keys so I switched to postgres - and when issuing db.create_all() - I can now see foreign keys and proper relationships but still don't understand how to access objects.

Comment: OK - I figured it out somewhat on my own - for anyone else who might stumble upon this -

Comment: First I mentioned 't.users.' didn't give back an error - well I could write t.anything and it will be accepted - that' s just adding a variable to the object - irrelevant.

Comment: The syntax that worked was -

Comment: t.user.append(user) - you append the user object to the team object.  The user object I'm guessing is a list including the user_id.  I went back into my db and sure enough the mapping was in the association table.  Very simple as I suspected - just took way too long to figure out!  I'm guessing everyone else figured this out on their own, but if not hope this helps.

Comment: Can you share the models team, user, player, etc? It will help to check foreign keys and the relationship.

Comment: The models are all in the code I originally posted.  It is all working well now -- really just my ignorance on how to use the objects.